# Why does this modrewrite affect other files?

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, seo

I have been using this following code to rewrite the request variable in a nested directory.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^demos/folder1/page\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^demos/folder1/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ demos/folder1/page.php?slug=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^demos/folder1/([^/]+)$ demos/folder1/page.php?slug=$1 [NC] /* ruins everything, with other links *
```

This is located in the .htaccess file in the root directory, not /folder1/. Any idea why it would be causing other .php files on the server to not display? I need only requests to /demo/folder1/page.php to be rewritten to /demo/folder1/REQUEST. What am I missing?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^demos/folder1/page\.php$ - [L,NC]

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]    

RewriteRule ^demos/folder1/([^/]+)/?$ demos/folder1/page.php?slug=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```